# unable to add azure fileshare to Recovery service vault backup policy through az cli command

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-backup-vault, azure-file-share

i am trying add AzureFileshare to recovery service vault backup policy through Az cli command in azure devops pipeline. but i could not succeed. below is the cli command

```
az backup protection enable-for-azurefileshare --resource-group vaultresourcegroup -- 
vault-name rsvault --policy-name filesharepolicy --storage-account sasample --azure-file- 
share fileshare1
```

below is the error i am getting

```
ERROR: Storage not found or not Supported.
```

am i missing anything here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ERROR: Storage not found or not supported.

According to this **[MS-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-storage/troubleshoot-azure-files#usererrorfileshareendpointunreachable--storage-account-not-found-or-not-supported)**, the above error occurs when the storage account may have been deleted or created in a different region (like France or Germany).

When I tried with a different region like (France) for the storage account, I too got the same error:

[image]

When I tried with the same region like (East US) for the storage account, it created a backup policy for the file share.

**Command and output:**

```
az backup protection enable-for-azurefileshare --policy-name policy1 --resource-group xxx --vault-name  azurefilesvault --storage-account "venkat789" --azure-file-share "share3" --output table
Name                                  ResourceGroup
------------------------------------  ---------------------
6b9c06e7-4277-xxxxxx                  xxxx
```

[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

**Reference:**
[Support Matrix for Azure file share backup by using Azure Backup - Azure Backup | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/azure-file-share-support-matrix#supported-regions)

Comment: in my case both storage account and recovery service vault are in westeurope in different resource groups.
hope in your command resource group refers vault resource group ?

Comment: it may work in same resource group, but we have deployed resources into separate resource group

Comment: In my side storage account in resource grp A(East us) and my recovery vault in resource grp B(East us) now I run the same command it worked perfectly. https://i.imgur.com/tZHGoql.png

Comment: did you move to resource to different resource group and then run the command, if so please create new storage account in different resource group and then run the command, i think it won't work.  also can you please tell me cli version

Comment: I created a new resource grp with a storage account with East US only https://i.imgur.com/Fz0vd66.png and executed with the above command only my azure-cli version == 2.56.0.

Comment: My recovery service vaults in different resource grp with east us location https://i.imgur.com/wX17COb.png

Comment: it was my bad, did not notice that storage account was already registered with another vault, due to that error was being thrown. thanks for your help